# Android widget button custom dialog

Tags: android, button, widget

Is it possible to open a custom dialog from widget button? I created a widget with a button. With [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) tutorial if i click ButtonP1 a toast msg appears. But i want a custom dialog to appear. There is also an intent example for the button in the tutorial but for my custom dialog it is not working, however if i want to open an activity with that it is working fine.
I want a custom dialog to appear when user clicks on a button on the widget.

Here is this code where Main.class is an activity:

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));

     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmain);
     Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
     configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
     PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP1, configPendingIntent);
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
 }
```

When i change Main.class to CustomizeDialog.class, nothing happens.

The CustomizeDialog.java looks like this in a nutshell:

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Activity mActivity;
public CustomizeDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
         mActivity = activity;
...
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == okButton)
        {
            dismiss();
            }
        if (v == cancelButton)
        {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 06.21.2011**

Thank to you guys, i was able to call an activity with framelayout which is almost what i wanted. However, I want to do this with a customdialog, but with the code i am using, it is not appearing when i click on the widget button:

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, CustomizeDialog.class);
     configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
     PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_THREE, configIntent, 0);
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP3, configPendingIntent);
```

If i change CustomizeDialog.class to Main.class, which is an activity, it is working fine.

Please find CustomDialog.class's structure above.

Answer (score 5):

Like Tanner already pointed out you should use an Activity for this.

In the manifest you have to add a few attributes to the dialog activity.

**android:launchMode="singleInstance"** - to place the activity (dialog) at the root of a new task, without this the activity will be placed on top of the main activity in your application.

**android:excludeFromRecents="true"** -  so you can't reach the dialog by long pressing the home-key.

**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"** - style it as a dialog.

```
<activity android:name=".InputDialog" 
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

In the dialog activity you have to call finish() on the activity after the user clicked on OK, Cancel or the back button. If you don't do this only the dialog will be closed and the activity will remain visible.

I wrote a how-to a while back when I faced the same problem, can be found [here on my blog.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120530025501/http://www.rochdev.com:80/2011/05/display-dialog-from-widget.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton been struggling with showing a dialog from a widget well atleast closing the activity when the dialog is canceled checked your project and added setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ etc to my dialog works perfectly thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to show the dialog in the activity that is opened by clicking on your widget. If you use something like a `FrameLayout` you can run an activity that appears to be hovering over the top of your home screen.

Comment: I don't want to open an activity. I just want a custom dialog to appear when user clicks on the button of the widget.

Comment: It has been a while since I have developed a widget, but what I do remember is that widgets are very restrictive in what you can do. From what I have seen all the widgets that do things like pop open windows are doing it via an Activity

Comment: Noone knows the solution? Idk how to start a pop up window or sg from an activity without making the activity appear

Comment: Have you looked at `FrameLayout`? Create an Activity whose layout is based on a `FrameLayout` and play with the width/height. This will cause the activity to run in a "frame" that appears much like a dialog itself. Think of it as manually building a dialog. Be creative and I'm sure you'll figure it out.